Error : No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one wagmi and tanstack/react-query
I'm trying to setup wagmi 2.x in my NextJs app and getting the following error.
I have already checked for any conflicting versions of @tanstack/react-query and react-query. There's only one version of @tanstack/react-query. As mentioned here and here
I have fixed my dependency versions as mentioned in the official codesandbox provided by wagmi here.
I'm attaching the code and my package.json below.
import {
    QueryClient,
    QueryClientProvider,
} from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { createConfig, http, WagmiProvider } from "wagmi";
import { mainnet, sepolia } from "wagmi/chains";

export default function MyApp({
    Component,
    pageProps,
}: AppProps) {
    const wagmiConfig = createConfig({
        chains: [mainnet, sepolia],
        connectors: [
            injected(),
        ],
        transports: {
            [mainnet.id]: http(),
            [sepolia.id]: http(),
        },
    });

    const queryClient = new QueryClient({
        defaultOptions: {
            queries: {
                staleTime: Infinity,
            },
        },
    });

    return (
        <div
            className={`w-full h-full min-w-screen min-h-screen bg-[#12192E] ${manrope.className}`}>
            <WagmiProvider config={wagmiConfig}>
                <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
                    <ConnectKitProvider>
                        <Provider store={store}>
                            <Navbar />
                            <Component {...pageProps} />
                        </Provider>
                    </ConnectKitProvider>
                </QueryClientProvider>
            </WagmiProvider>
        </div>
    );
}

{
    "name": "test-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@tanstack/react-query": "5.0.5",
        "@types/node": "20.3.1",
        "@types/react": "18.2.12",
        "@types/react-dom": "18.2.5",
        "@types/react-modal": "^3.16.2",
        "@wagmi/connectors": "4.0.1",
        "connectkit": "^1.7.3",
        "ethers": "^6.7.0",
        "next": "13.4.5",
        "viem": "2.0.0",
        "wagmi": "2.0.1"
    }
}

It seems to work perfectly fine on the codesandbox so it's very weird that the same version of the dependencies are not working here. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks! :)
